# Run Java Script in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have bought one WordPress theme which have Live Chat button in header. Its support link to open chat. But I have got java script to open button. I am learning php and does not know how can I run java script on button press WordPress.

I have code in wordpress header theme is like below

```
<?php }if( !empty( $king->cfg['topInfoLiveChat'] ) ){ ?>    
                <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( $king->cfg['topInfoLiveChat'] ); ?>" class="chat">
                    <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> <?php _e('Live Chat', 'arkahost' ); ?>
                </a>
```

Zopim chat have given me script to run is like below.

```
$zopim.livechat.window.show();
```

They have given example to include like below

```
<a href="javascript:$zopim.livechat.window.show()"><img src="INSERT_IMG_SRC_HERE"/></a>
```

But if I use like above my design getting changed. Anyone can please help me how can I integrate this script in my above codes ?

Thanks

Comment: You can install an plugin to insert code on the Footer - this way, you can insert scripts without change the theme files.

Comment: You can use a plugin for custom javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you learn some javascript and jQuery? You can run codes when an event happen. Like you have clicked a `ahref` element with `.chat` class.

```
<script>
    jQuery("a.chat").on("click", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       // Your code goes here. Example:
       $zopim.livechat.window.show();
    });
</script>
```

P/s: you should have a better selector like `.header a.chat`, or all `ahref` element have `.chat` class will show your Zopim windows when users clicked on it.

Comment: Hi ! I just need add code that You have written or I need modify any other codes also ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you only need add my code to anywhere, or custom javascript section if your theme have that. There's no need to edit any theme's files.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to add the code in JS like:

```
$zopim.livechat.window.show();
```

and fire it on click event on your button, you need just to add the script (if you have jquery) to your file (with button):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('a.chat').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $zopim.livechat.window.show();
  });
</script>
```

or add it to the JS file, that included into your page:

```
jQuery('a.chat').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $zopim.livechat.window.show();
  });
```

Where `a.chat` is the link (`<a href=""></a>` tag) and `.chat` is the class name of your link, like in your example. You can add the parrent elements.

`e.preventDefault()` - default event for the link will not fire

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remember use 'jQuery' instead of '$' in wordrpess.